# iphone 5 merged mail contacts become unmerged

Tags: contacts, iphone

I have linked all my contacts phone numbers and their e-mail addresses from Hotmail together to see their phone numbers and mail addresses in one place. After a while ı found out that all separated again. It has happened twice. Do you know why?

Comment: Are they double?

Comment: There are two entries one for phone number and one for e-mail for the same person.